# Why does my enemy go the other way when the player moves more than a few pixels away from (0, 0)?

Tags: javascript

My enemy initially goes to the player when the game starts, but when the player moves away from its starting position, it goes away.

Code:

```
// taken from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/moving-a-sprite-towards-an-x-and-y-coordinate?answertab=votes&newreg=00cf6f4d9b50405dbea4cd1e5b328e87

// Rotate us to face the player
this.rotation = Math.atan2(obj.y - this.y, obj.x - this.x);

// Move towards the player
this.x += Math.cos(this.rotation) * this.speed;
this.y += Math.sin(this.rotation) * this.speed;
```

Note: the images are rectangular.

Comment: When you copy paste code from the internet, and it doesn't work out of the box for your specific needs, you need to stop and understand what it does, so you can know what is wrong with it. Here, I suggest you spend a day or two understanding the trigonometry you're using. Trigonometry is a must have skill in game dev.

Comment: Hmm, ok, but I understand it. Although I might try to look into it deeper. Thanks @Vaillancourt!

Comment: It's not obvious to me why this code would cause a problem. It is overcomplicated as Cool guy says in an answer below, but the math looks correct to my eye. Can you give us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to go towrds `obj`, do

```
let dir = {
    x: obj.x - this.x,
    y: obj.y - this.y
};

let length = Math.sqrt(dir.x*dir.x + dir.y*dir.y);

this.x += dir.x * this.speed / length;
this.y += dir.y * this.speed / length;
```

You should also take into account the deltatime for same speed per different fps